# Windowing function COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY) is not working for me

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have this data set:

[image]

I want to produce this:

[image]

Here is my query, it's not producing the desired result. I'm trying to count `order_ids` and partiton by country. What am I doing wrong?

Note that if I don't include order_id in the GROUP BY, I get the following error `order_id is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function.`

```
SELECT country,  
       COUNT(repeat_customer_id) repeat_customer,
       COUNT(order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY country) total_orders
FROM table
GROUP BY country, order_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a window function here, just normal aggregation grouping by *country*

```
SELECT country,  
       COUNT(repeat_customer_id) repeat_customer,
       COUNT(*) total_orders
FROM table
GROUP BY country;
```

Comment: Then your data is different to that which is shown in your question - do you allow NULLs? Try `count(order_id)`